# How do I pass a python variable to a website via PHP

Tags: php, python, variables, post

I believe that I am missing something basic but I cannot figure it out.  I have defined a variable in a python script running on my local client.  I would like to pass this variable to my website via PHP.

Here is the code I have in my python script (just a simplified example):

```
userdata = {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "password": "jdoe123"}
resp = requests.post('example.com/specificPage.php', 
data=userdata) 
print(resp.status_code, resp.reason)
print(resp.text)
```

When I run this in python it looks fine and the variable values for firstname (John), lastname (Doe) and password (jdoe123) show up when I look at print(resp.text).  This matches what I have seen in other examples.

This is the code I have on my webpage:

```
<?php
    $firstname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstname"]);
    $lastname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["lastname"]);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["password"]);
    echo "firstname: $firstname lastname: $lastname password: $password";
?>
```

When I refresh my webpage the variable values do not show up.  Because the webpage is on a third party shared server, I am assuming that I need to log in to the webserver but I may be wrong about this.

What am I missing?

I have in the past used PHP to post information from an HTML form into a sql database on the webserver (which requires a login password), and from which I can then retrieve this posted information.  However, I am trying to avoid this extra step if possible.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing shows up when you refresh the page in the browser because you haven't POSTed anything to it!

Comment: You cannot access the POST data from a separate browser/session from where the Python is running

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  Can you provide me some guidance on how to go about doing this?  I am pretty new to programming and I am assuming that I need to use something similar to what I did when I posted to the mysql database (e.g., $link=mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) to put the data on the webserver.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I process a csv file locally with python that results in some data that I have defined as variables (e.g., total dollars spent).  I would like to dynamically update my third-party hosted website with this data by passing these variables.

Comment: And you're storing this data where? In a database? In a file?

Comment: In a file.  (Separately, I also encode this data to send via an update email in html format).

Comment: So, you'll probably need an endpoint that receives the data and does something with it (writes it to a file), and then another page that reads the file and displays the data, right?

Comment: Yes.  That sound right.  Does this file need to be transferred to the shared server directory?